# How to set image resource in ImageAdapter and get taht resource on click listner

Tags: android, gridview, baseadapter

I want to set image resource like `id` or any name to image that are dynamically created but I'm not able to do that. Here is my code:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    public Context mContext;
    public String id ;
    public String [] arr;
    public String[] mThumbIds;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c,String id) {
        mContext = c;
        this.id = id;
        arr = this.id.split(",");
        populateArray();
    }

    public void populateArray(){
        mThumbIds = new String[arr.length];
        for(int i= 0; i<arr.length; i++){
            mThumbIds[i] = "http://www.mysiteurl.com?r=index.php"+arr[i];
        }

    }

    public int getCount() {
        return mThumbIds.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);

        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }
        Picasso.with(mContext).load(mThumbIds[position]).into(imageView);
        //imageView.setImageResource(Integer.parseInt(mThumbIds[position]));
        return imageView;
    }
}
```

I have an array of ids which I pass in constructor of this class. What I want is to set these ids to my images that are created by this piece of code, so that I can get that id on one of these image click listener.

```
// create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView;
    if (convertView == null) {
        // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);

    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }
    Picasso.with(mContext).load(mThumbIds[position]).into(imageView);
    //imageView.setImageResource(Integer.parseInt(mThumbIds[position]));
    return imageView;
}
```

Here is my fragment from which I'm calling the `ImageAdapter` class and set the click listener of images.

```
GridView gridview = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.gridview);
gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(getActivity(),id));

gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                            int position, long id) {
        ChartPageFragment.fromSearch = true;

        ChartPageFragment newFragment = new ChartPageFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        //String arr=v.getTag();
        args.putString("id","34778");
        newFragment.setArguments(args);

        FragmentTransaction transaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        // Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
        // and add the transaction to the back stack so the user can navigate back
        transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(newFragment.getClass().getName());
        // Commit the transaction
        transaction.commit();
    }
});
```

I am stuck on this any idea how to do that.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the same logic you are using in the adapter. Split the string `id` and take the corresponding id using `position` argument in `onItemClick` of the `GridView`.

Try this,

```
private String getClickedItemId(int position){
    // id is the variable containing all your ids
    String [] arr = id.split(",");
    if(position < arr.length)
        return arr[poistion];
    else
        return null;
}
```

Call this function in your `onItemClick` as follows.

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
    ChartPageFragment.fromSearch = true;

    ChartPageFragment newFragment = new ChartPageFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("id", getClickedItemId(position));
    newFragment.setArguments(args);

    ...
}
```